# Arduino Uno/Nano + ML

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, sensors

I couldn't find any clear answers elsewhere, hence I'm asking here.
I have a TensorFlow/TensorFlow Lite model which I have already trained on some sensor data.
Now, how can I utilize this model on my Arduino Nano/Uno to perform some other functions like moving a motor?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of Tensorflow lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers) states:

> The core runtime just fits in 16 KB on an Arm Cortex M3 and can run many basic models.

So the Tensorflow lite runtime itself needs 16kB of - I guess - RAM. That would be 8 times of what the Uno/Nano actually has. If they mean program memory, then it would fit, since Uno/Nano has 32kB of flash.

Though it would still not work:

> TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers is written in C++ 17 and requires a 32-bit platform.

The Uno/Nano uses the Atmega328p, which is an 8-bit microcontroller.

So all in all: No, you cannot use Tensorflow lite on an Uno/Nano. You should look at the "Supported Platforms" section of the linked Tensorflow Lite documentation to choose a board, that fits your needs.

Comment: FYI: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-33-ble-sense/get-started-with-machine-learning/  (it's board with Nano "form factor" - 3.3V only + Cortex M4 with FPU)